# For ratio and proportion or percentage problems when do we divid a number by a fraction?

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

Particularly for calculating some ratio and proportion problems we need to divide a number by a fraction. I am finding it difficult to interpret what this signifies. Obviously multiplying by a fraction signifies a part of the value but what is the analytical interpretation when I divide a number by a fraction?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Please edit to give specific examples of the situation(s) you are concerned about.